# How to query sqlite db using a dropdown list in flask web app?

Tags: python, html, sqlite, flask

I have a flask web app that contains a dropdown list that will allow the user to select which shoe they want and I would like to query the database using the dropdown list and display the shoe information and image but I can't quite work out the flow/logic of how I should go about it. I've only been using flask and SQLite for a few weeks so I would appreciate any advice!
Dropdown list in /choosebrand and the corresponding image from the DB should be displayed in the next page, /analyse.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the image is stored as a BLOB in the DB but I also have the images in the static folder. If there is even an easier way where I can just use the dropdown list to search for the filename in that folder instead of querying the database, I would much appreciate it :)

main.py:

```
#CHOOSE BRAND:
@app.route('/choosebrand')
def choosebrand():
    return render_template('choosebrand.html')

# ANALYSE SHOE (also displays feature matching results):
@app.route('/analyse', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def analyse():
    #displays dropdown info inputted by user
    brandName = request.form['brandName']
    model = request.form['model']
    colourway = request.form['colourway']
    return render_template('analyseshoe.html', brandName=brandName, model=model, colourway=colourway)
```

choosebrand.html dropdown list:

```
<form class="shoelist" method="POST" action="{{ url_for('analyse') }}">
                <div>
                    <label>Brand</label>
                        <select id = "brandName" name="brandName">
                            <option value = "">--SELECT--</option>
                            <option value = "Yeezy">Yeezy</option>
                            getBrandName()
                        </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label>Model</label>
                        <select id = "model" name="model">
                            <option value = "">--SELECT--</option>
                            <option value = "Boost 350">Boost 350</option>
                            <option value = "Boost 500">Boost 500</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <label>Colourway</label>
                        <select id = "colourway" name="colourway">
                            <option value = "">--SELECT--</option>
                            <option value = "Cloud White">Cloud White</option>
                            <option value = "Zebra">Zebra</option>
                            <option value = "Beluga V2">Beluga V2</option>
                            <option value = "Black">Black</option>
                            <option value = "Citrin">Citrin</option>
                            <option value = "Triple White">Triple White</option>
                            <option value = "Yecheil">Yecheil</option>
                            <option value = "Yeshaya">Yeshaya</option>
                            <option value = "Bone White">Bone White</option>
                            <option value = "Salt">Salt</option>                               <option value = "Soft Vision">Soft Vision</option>
                            <option value = "Stone">Stone</option>
                            <option value = "Utility Black">Utility Black</option>
                        </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Analyse Shoe">
                </div>                       
            </form>
```

analyseshoe.html:

```
  <div>
            <h1 class="heading">Analyse Shoe</h1>
            <p class="selection">Authenticity of your {{brandName}} {{model}} {{colourway}}:</p>

        </div>
```

Shoe.Db:

```
try:
    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('Shoe.db')
    sqlite_create_table_query = ''' CREATE TABLE ShoeDetails (
                                shoeId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                brandName TEXT NOT NULL,
                                model TEXT NOT NULL,
                                colourway TEXT NOT NULL,
                                shoeImage BLOB NOT NULL); '''
```

Comment: did you run it with debug mode in terminal/console/cmd.exe to see error messages ? What is `getBrandName()` in HTML ? You can't run Python code in HTML. You can only use `{% %}` to use some code in HTML to generate HTML which is send to browser. Browser will send dropdown value to `analyse()`  and it should use `SQL` to `SELECT` value from database and send it in new template.

Comment: @furas : thanks for spotting the getBrandName(), it wasn't supposed to be there! No errors, my issue is more so that I don't know what next step to take to query the DB based on the dropdown input and display it to a template.

Comment: inside `analyse()` after getting `request.form[...]` and before `render_template()` you have to use `SELECT * FROM ShoeDetails WHERE ...` to get data from database. First: you have to know how to write SQL queries. Second: you have to use this query with `sqliteConnection.execute(query, (arg1, arg2, arg2,...))`

Comment: Flask documentation: [sqlite3](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/sqlite3/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

after `request.form` you have to excute SQL query with selected values and result send to `render_template`

More or less like this:

```
def analyse():
    #displays dropdown info inputted by user
    selected_brandName = request.form['brandName']
    selected_model = request.form['model']
    selected_colourway = request.form['colourway']

    query = "SELECT * FROM ShoeDetails WHERE brandName = ? AND model = ? AND colourway = ?"
    args = (selected_brandName, selected_model, selected_colourway)

    cur = sqliteConnection.execute(query, args)
    all_results = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()

    return render_template('analyseshoe.html', results=all_results)
```

Because some variables had the same name in Python, HTML's form and in database so I use prefix `selected_` to make it more readable.

And now in template you can use `results`

If `shoeImage` keeps filename of image on disk in preferred folder `/static`

```
{% for item in results %}

<img src="/static/{{ item['shoeImage'] }}>

{% endfor %}
```

But if you keep image in database then it makes more problems. Because you would have to decode it in `base64` to embed it directly in HTML

```
{% for item in results %}

<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {{ item['shoeImage'] }}>

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've tried the code above and ran on localhost with debugging and it seems to be getting to the /static folder but not finding the image.                                                
127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2020 00:38:41] "[37mPOST /analyse HTTP/1.1[0m" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [04/May/2020 00:38:41] "[33mGET /static/ HTTP/1.1[0m" 404 -

Comment: what do you have in in database in`shoeImage` ? And in `item['shoeImage']` ? It seems it is empty and it creates path `/static/`. If you would have i.e string `image.jpg` then you should see `/static/image.jpg` instead of `/static/`

Comment: In the database, the shoeImage is stored as a BLOB but I also have the images in the /static folder so if that way is easier I can do it that way.

Comment: if you have image in folder then you should keep its name in `shoeImage`, not `BLOB` and use this name in HTML `<img src="/static/{{ item['shoeImage'] }}">`. For test you can put directly filename `<img src="/static/image.jpg">`

Comment: I think I've found my issue. I'm not assigning a shoeImage var to the /static folder as I initially wanted to use the shoeImage from the database